# Task Manager not able to connect to Job Manager

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to upgrade our Flink cluster from 1.4.2 to 1.7.2

When I bring up the cluster, the task managers refuse to connect to the job managers with the following error.

```
2019-03-14 10:34:41,551 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        
- Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@cluster:22671] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@cluster:22671]] Caused by: [cluster: Name or service not known]
```

Now, this works correctly if I add the following line into the `/etc/hosts` file.

```
x.x.x.x job-manager-address.com cluster
```

Why is Flink 1.7.2 connecting to JM using `cluster` in the address? Flink 1.4.2 used to have the job manager's address instead of the word `cluster`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jobmanager.sh` script was being invoked with a second argument called `cluster`.

```
${Flink_HOME}/bin/jobmanager.sh start cluster
```

Prior to 1.5, the script expected an execution mode (local or cluster) but this is no longer the case. Invoking the script without the second argument solved this issue.

```
${Flink_HOME}/bin/jobmanager.sh start
```

---

- http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Flink-1-7-2-Task-Manager-not-able-to-connect-to-Job-Manager-td26707.html
- https://github.com/apache/flink/commit/d61664ca64bcb82c4e8ddf03a2ed38fe8edafa98
- https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/c6878aca6c5aeee46581b4d6744b31049db9de95/flink-dist/src/main/flink-bin/bin/jobmanager.sh#L21-L25